# procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new in nodejs. I am getting an issue when we run `mongod.exe` file in `cmd` to start the mongodb server.

I am getting:

> `ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-10.dll.`

Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and it solved by updating windows or by installing the following package.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Comment: i have updated the window but when  i try to install the package.I am getting ---->>"this is not applicable to ur computer".